# How can I wrap text with one long line to specifc width with pretty block?

Tags: bash, aix, fold

Folks, I am having a text with one long line and need to justify it with specific width (I know fold can do this) but the needed output should be like a block which might needs to insert spaces between words like emacs, but I don't have emacs , so can you please advise on this?

[image]

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Cyrus I tried to add already but I couldn't get what I needed, I still need to manage how to input here, can I add it as a photo?

Comment: i added a photo for what i need

Comment: For DIN A5 landscape output: `nroff -dpaper=a5l -Tlatin file`

Comment: $ nroff -dpaper=a5l -Tlatin text
nroff: 1004-004 The -dpaper=a5l is an option that is not valid.

Comment: or try `nroff -dpaper=letter -Tlatin file`. I use `GNU nroff (groff) version 1.21`.

Comment: nroff contains many flags and needs deeper look, i am afraid the last command gave error also

Answer (score 0):

Direct translation to the [fold(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fold) command

```
fold --width=80 --spaces
```

Comment: but this won't block the output , it will just break lines so each output line segment is as wide as possible reference to -w for example 50, the needed output should be like a block paragraph